# SQLiteDatabse and ContentProvider in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I want to create my application's own call logs. How to use SQLiteDatabase or/and ContentProvider in my application to store and retrieve call log information. I am very confused in SQLiteDatabese and in ContentProvider. Please help me. I am very confused and stuck here.

thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need implement the SQLiteOpenHelper and create your databases with an SQL for storing log.

Then use your instance to open(), getWritableDatabase() to write to, and remember to close() after all operations.

Comment: Then please give me light on contentprovider. After implementing SQLiteOpenHelper how to get the content of database to see on the screen? Using contentprovider? In some app i seen that class extends with contentprovider has inner class extends with SQLiteOpenHelper. why? (e.g. Notepad app)

Comment: You don't need a ContentProvider, you application can access the database directly. ContentProviders are used to share information with another applications.